# How can I install a Canon Pixma MG2140 printer/scanner?

Tags: installation, drivers, printing, canon, pixma

I have just got the printer/scanner. It was automatically detected, but no printer driver was found in the driver database for this particular model. Searching turned up the following .deb - can I trust a driver from this site?

http://www.driverlook.com/download/2880/canon-pixma-mg2140-mg2150-ij-printer-driver-linux-deb/

Comment: please see if any of the suggestions here work for your model.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working

Comment: No, you can't trust some random site redistributing Canon's drivers. By far the easiest way is to install them from the Software Center. fossfreedom's comment above has the details.

Comment: @fossfreedom Odd. I tried searching for "Canon cnijfilter" as instructed and it came up with nothing. I tried searching for just 'canon' and looking at the (53!) technical items, but couldn't find anything that looked promising. 'Canon pixma' also yielded nothing. Any idea why this search might not be producing anything for me?

Comment: yeh - it was missing an important bit of info - please look again - I've amended the answer to include the missing PPA.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to install the original Canon Drivers. I've got a Canon Pixma MP630 and it works without problems.

You should install the [scanner](http://www.canon.de/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG2140.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:83-875495&page=1&type=download) and the [printer](http://www.canon.de/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG2140.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:83-875491&page=1&type=download) driver. (Scroll down and click the *Download* button. If the links don't work, go to [canon.com](http://canon.com) and search under *Support* for your driver.)

For the Canon driver I've had a little bit struggle and had to edit something. I don't know if this is necessary for your driver, too, but maybe [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/105310/46531) could help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed kubuntu 12.04 . I have a Canon MG2150. The printer application installs without a problem the printer (general driver canon mg2100 series). However, the scanner is another story, I downloaded ScanGear 1.8 - Linux version (deb) from the Canon webpage and installed it, then when i use GIMP, and click to "Create" appears now within the options Scangear, and from there it controls your scanner pretty much ok... I still have 30 GB with a windows 7 partition, windows office 2007 and no internet, to run some work or other programs when i have compatibility issues, but i hardly use it. Of course in windows i have too the original printer drivers. I´ve tried a lot of things but the above mentioned is the one that has worked for me...Now i dont have to go to windows to use my scanner. Hope this helps...