# Change printer sleep time

Tags: printing, configuration, sleep, brother

Background: Brother HL-2270DW printer configured with my Xubuntu 12.10 over my home network. Whenever it finishes printing something, the fan keeps running for about 2 hours before going to sleep.

Question: Is there any way I can decrease this "awake" time, so that the fan stops running sooner? For example, is there a configuration file I am able to edit?

Comment: Not a Ubuntu issue. Try Brother

Comment: I posted this here because I figured that there was some way to control printers from Ubuntu, like [CUPS](http://localhost:631/), but CUPS can't change the sleep time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the answer at a [Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+question/167083) from someone experiencing a similar problem.  After somehow starting to search for a "ppd" file as a possible solution, I stumbled on said Launchpad question.

So when I installed the lpr and cups drivers from the Brother site, it created a ppd file at /usr/share/cups/model, with the name of my printer model.  So I opened cups, navigated to `Administration -> Manage Printers -> Brother_HL-2270DW_series -> Administration/Modify Printer`, chose Brother as the make, and added the ppd file from said location. This installed the correct drivers, giving me full access to all printer features, including sleep time!

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/144201/110837) on Ask Ubuntu. People say printer configuration (sleep time...) works well with Original Drivers

Comment: No, that didn't work - I followed all the instructions, and it ended up with a "printer not connected" error when I tried to print a test page. So the only configuration I've gotten to work so far is using the generic drivers.

Comment: This Might help. http://chadchenault.blogspot.in/2012/05/brother-hl-2270dw-printer-driver.html

Comment: Well, I followed the instructions (Both with 64-bit drivers and 32-bit drivers, even though I'm on 32-bit), but it didn't work. When I clicked "Find New Printers", however, two came up, and one of them had that "_pdl" thing. When I tried to print, it worked, but it didn't have an option to set the sleep time. I found the answer, and I think your suggestions helped me using some different parameters, and that led me to the solution, so thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure, but I'm think that blog's note about needing to make sure the connection was dnssd://blahblah._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/ is necessary. Again, thanks for helping!